# Jenkins - Disable sandbox for Jenkinsfiles from SCM

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Following script works if I run it without the sandbox. But if with Sandbox it fails for me: `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field groovy.util.slurpersupport.NoChildren value`

I'm fine with deactivating the sandbox, cause I trust my own code. My problem is, that I can't run it when retrieving the pipeline code as a jenkins file from a SCM-Server. Pulling files from a Server permanently enables the Sandbox?

What of these actions, which I perform in this code, does trigger the sandbox mechanism? How can I figure that out?

- How can I run my code base which pulls it's code from a SCM without a sandbox?
- Or, how can I allow those exceptions?
- Is there a other way to call those methods like `script.myDangerousMethod`?

#### reproduce:

jenkins -> New Item -> "Pipeline"

copy&paste:

```
stage('only'){
    strXML = '<devices><property name="GivenName" value="123"/></devices>'
    def list2 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(strXML) 
    println list2.device[0].@value.text()
}
```

[X]/[__]  Sandbox

Comment: Try defining a method to do this and using the `@Whitelisted` annotation.

Comment: @Matt Schuchard How shuld I do that? just take the code abouve, define a function and write `@Whitelisted` abouve it? - Sry, I'm a newbe in Groovy/Java. I'm from C/python.

Comment: @MattSchuchard `@Whitelisted
def methodName() {`
    `//... code from question`
    `return 0}`
`stage('only'){methodName()}` -- does not work, I got you wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: @MattSchuchard sry, `1: unable to resolve class Whitelisted ,  unable to find class for annotation
 @ line 1, column 1.`

Comment: @CuttonEye Did you get this to work?

Comment: nope, still copy&paste 1200 lines of code. can't circumvent the sandbox, which is active when I'm pulling the pipe line code from a repo. So it's c&p -.-.